# How do I set intent data to current activity editText?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to transfer two numerical inputs from one activity to another's UI but when I click the button to change intent it crashes.

I get the following in logcat:  http://pastebin.com/zkWPcSNZ , which suggests a problem with the way I parsed the data to the editTexts in CalcResult.

My question is what is wrong with the way I'm trying to pass the data to the CalcResult editText.Is there an alternative method of acheiving this?

My two classes look like this for reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    //variables for xml objects
    EditText offsetLength,offsetDepth,ductDepth;
    Button calculate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting the variables to the xml id's and setting the click listener on the calc button
        offsetLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offLength);
        offsetDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offDepth);
        ductDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ductDepth);
        calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(this);//don't cast the listener to OnClickListener


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
            String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
            String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 

            double tri1,tri2;
            double marking1,marking2;

            double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
            double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
            double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth)
                    ;
            marking1 = Math.pow(off1,2) + Math.pow(off2,2);
            tri1 = (float)off2/(float)off1;
            tri2 = (float)off3/Math.atan((float)tri1);
            marking2 = (float)off3/Math.atan(tri2);


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalcResult.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("numbers", marking1);
            myIntent.putExtra("numbers", marking2);

            startActivity(myIntent);


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Must enter a numeric value!");

        }

    }


}
```

This is the activity that I'm passing the data to:

```
public class CalcResult extends MainActivity
{
    EditText result1,result2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        result1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
        result2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        double mark1 = bundle.getDouble("number1");
        double mark2 = bundle.getDouble("number2");

        int a = Integer.valueOf(result1.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.valueOf(result2.getText().toString());

        result1.setText(a + "  ");
        result2.setText(b + "  ");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you are putting your extras with same key "`numbers`" , and you are trying to retreive them by another keys "number1" and "number2". your code should be like this :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalcResult.class);
myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
myIntent.putExtra("number2", marking2);
```

and to retreive them you should use :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double mark1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
double mark2 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number2", 0);
```

And then , set the variables on your EditTexts like this :

```
result1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
result2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);
result1.setText(mark1+"");
result2.setText(mark2+"");
```

Comment: This is an error made by the OP but not the cause of the app's crash. `getDouble(String key)` _"Returns the value associated with the given key, or 0.0 if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key"_

Comment: if you look at the code in which he sends the extra variables, the key he used are the same `myIntent.putExtra("numbers", marking1);` , So the key is "numbers" , and he is trying to retreive the double extra of the key "number1" "and number2", so it will return 0. So even if assuming that he has setting the text to the EditText , it will show nothing

Comment: It will return 0 but this won't throw an exception. You will just have `mark1 = 0;` and `mark2 = 0;`

Comment: yes you are right (+1) , i didn't see the logcat he provides , the error is he is trying to retreive the text from both of `EditTexts` , and they are Empty , so when  he try to parse the result it will give `NumberFormatException` (y)

Comment: Ok I tried your fix and it works.Might have to go back to the drawing board for some of my calculation though as they seem a bit off.

Comment: Ya thanks I checked @Houcine fix and it worked. :) Do you have any code example of swiping between activities?

Comment: @user2815899 : here is a tutorial about how to switch between activities : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android

Comment: I think you misunderstood,how to "swipe" between activities?

Answer (score 1):

When you start your second activity, both editText are empty

So when you do :

```
int a = Integer.valueOf(result1.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.valueOf(result2.getText().toString());
```

it's equivalent to :

```
int a = Integer.valueOf("");
int b = Integer.valueOf("");
```

which throws the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

If you want to set them the values you passed through both activities, you can just do :

```
double mark1 = bundle.getDouble("number1");
double mark2 = bundle.getDouble("number2");

result1.setText(mark1 + "  ");
result2.setText(mark2 + "  ");
```

Comment: When I use this code I just get 0.0 and 0.0 for calculation results.I think it may be a problem with the way the data is being passed over.

Comment: Now you can check @Houcine stated. You're passing the same key in your intent.

Comment: Ya thanks I checked @Houcine fix and it worked. :) Do you have any code example of swiping between activities?

Comment: @user2815899 http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android : this is a tutorial about **how to switch between activities and pass data between them**

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same name for your extras when sending the intent, try correcting them.